# List users connected to me

Tags: users, relations, user-profile, relatedto, current-user

I have a relationship field within my member profile. It allows users to connect to each other, i can list those that currentUser is connected to, but i need to list all other members that are connected to currentUser, i.e. a reverse relationship.

I have this, but it just lists those that the currentUser is connected to, not the reverse, where am i going wrong?

```
{% set myReverseConnections = craft.users.relatedTo(currentUser) %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
    {% set myReverseConnections = craft.users.relatedTo({
        targetElement: currentUser,
        field: 'yourCustomRelationshipField'
    }) %}
```